# ftp upload behind a proxy with cmd

Tags: upload, proxy, ftp, cmd

I can't upload a file, it hangs at :

```
150 opening data connection for file.txt
```

The connection seems okay, I run this script :

```
open proxyserver proxyport
user@ftp.something.com
password
cd try
bin
quote pasv
put C:\file.txt
quit
```

I have no choice but to close the connection with ctrl+c and I have this message :

```
425 Can't open data connection.
421 Service not available, closing control connection.
```

It's okay with filezilla but I have to use a batch.
Thanks in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

See the URL below for this advice:

QUOTE `Many FTP clients do not support PASV transfers. For example, the
standard FTP.EXE built into Windows does not support this feature. The
user can still do a "quote PASV", which will tell the server to enter
PASV mode, but the client still will not work in this mode. (This is a
common problem, users enter "quote PASV" but things still don't work).`
 END QUOTE

use ncftp - available for free from http://www.ncftp.com

http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/configure-ftp-exe-use-passive-mode-pasv-t3655119.html

Comment: I configure ncftp firewall like that : 
`firewall-type=2
firewall-host=proxyserver
firewall-user=user@ftp.something.com
firewall-password=password
firewall-port=proxyport`

but when I type : `ncftp ftp.something.com` it keeps telling me : 
`You're already logged in Sleeping 15 seconds...`